# javascript tolocaletimestring() not working in some PC's

Tags: javascript

```js
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Time</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I have made a simple page to display time in AM/PM format, it's working fine in my PC. But i have tested this same code in my friend's PC , the time is displayed there in 24 hour format not in AM/PM format.

Note : We are using chrome as test browser (version no: 72.0.3626.109 (Official Build) (64-bit))

I have attached the failure case (Not working in other PC)

[image]

Comment: The result of `toLocaleTimeString()` depends of PC's OS settings. (change the date format from 12 to 24 hours in your friend OS and you'll get the desired result)

Comment: your code should not dependant on the target machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can ask your code to work correctly by adding more to it. calling `toLocaleTimeString()` without arguments depends on the implementation, the default locale, and the default time zone.

you can add rule to `toLocaleTimeString` to make it print time in AM/PM format by passing `{hour12: true}` as an option to it like,

```js
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: true });
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Time</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

you can find more options [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)

Comment: Can simplify the locale to just `'en'`

Comment: now i understood , when we force to use as 12 hour(hour12:true)  format it's working in my Friend's PC also!!